# How to export dataGridView data Instantly to Excel on button click?

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have 10k rows and 15 column in my data grid view. I want to export this data to an excel sheet o button click. I have already tried with the below code.

```
private void btExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook =  app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);        
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;                   
        app.Visible = true;
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;                  
        for(int i=1;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1;i++)
        {
             worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i-1].HeaderText;
        }    
        for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working for me but **it is taking lots of time to** complete exporting process.

**Is it possible to export from dataGridView (with 10k rows)to excel instantly on a button click?**

Other than this, when I tried copy all dataGridview contents to clip board and then paste it to excel sheet manually, it happen almost instantly.

**So is there a way to copy all dataGridView cells to clip board and paste it to excel sheet(with cell formatting) on a button click?**

I have code for copy to clipboard as below, but I don't know how to paste it in to a new excel sheet by opening it.

```
        private void copyAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }
```

Please help with an example. I am new to C#.

Comment: Almost all answer here write a (HtmlTextWriter) string or have Interop code. DO NOT USE EITHER. This will cause you problems later on with DateTime and Decimal formatting. Also Excel will give a warning because you are not generating a "real" Excel file but a HTML page with an .xls extension. Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47293207/5836671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513057/5836671).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I solved this by simple copy and paste method. I don't know it is the best way to do this but,for me it works good and almost instantaneously. Here is my code.

```
    private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you think your solution best answers your question, you should accept it.

Comment: This doesn't copy the headers which is the most important to have.

Comment: I was able to grab the header text by setting the clipboard copy mode to select headers also: `        DataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
        DataGridView1.MultiSelect = True
        DataGridView1.SelectAll()`

Comment: @Jake, ya it is working really great and added Mack step also to copy the header row.

Comment: How can I export these to an exist Excel file's specific rows? Specific row can be determined by this: Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[15, 1]; How can I append data to an exist Excel file?

Comment: @MeysamTolouee I needed to know the same thing, I figured out how to save my results, I posted my code below.

Comment: This works for me and many other people I created the Application for, but  for one user it creates an image in Excel.  It is not located in a Cell although it looks like it is in A1.  I cannot seem to figure out anything wrong with the code.  Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: So I am using this code, and on some machine in production it does paste an image. It looks like bitmap representation of the data being pasted by "PasteSpecial()" function. No idea how to resolve this.

Comment: How do I copy also the format and the backcolor cell from the dataGridView? The code above copy only the data, without the format of the cell (wrap cell, merge cell, backcolor cell, font )

Comment: Don't use the clipboard. It is unreliable with larger datasets and will not always paste in all of the data.

Comment: There will be a memory leak issue because some COM objects created are not released. Namely the Excel.Column, Excel.WorkBooks, Excel.Worksheets,Excel.Range COM Objects.
DO not use 2 Dot functions when using COM Objects.
refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-do-i-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/158752#158752

Answer (score 37):

This is a great question and I was surprised at how difficult it was to find a clear and complete answer, most of the answers I found were either sudo-code or not 100% complete.

I was able to create a complete solution to copy and save the data from my DataGridView to an excel file based on Jake's answer so I'm posting my complete solution in the hopes that it can help other new comers to c# like myself :)

First off, you will need the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference in your project. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx) on how to add it.

My Code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
    sfd.FileName = "Inventory_Adjustment_Export.xls";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // Copy DataGridView results to clipboard
        copyAlltoClipboard();

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Application xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

        xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false; // Without this you will get two confirm overwrite prompts
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // Format column D as text before pasting results, this was required for my data
        Excel.Range rng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D:D").Cells;
        rng.NumberFormat = "@";

        // Paste clipboard results to worksheet range
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

        // For some reason column A is always blank in the worksheet. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        // Delete blank column A and select cell A1
        Excel.Range delRng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A:A").Cells;
        delRng.Delete(Type.Missing);
        xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1").Select();

        // Save the excel file under the captured location from the SaveFileDialog
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = true;
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlexcel.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlexcel);

        // Clear Clipboard and DataGridView selection
        Clipboard.Clear();
        dgvItems.ClearSelection();

        // Open the newly saved excel file
        if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sfd.FileName);
    }
}

private void copyAlltoClipboard()
{
    dgvItems.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dgvItems.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}

private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Occurred while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: // For some reason column A is always blank in the worksheet.

As @Rahul mentioned below, the first blank column can be avoided in the clipboard copy by adding `dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;` (this hides the Row Header column). You can reshow it at the end of the clipboard copy if needed.

Comment: @Cornelius How do I make the copy/export process task continue in the background or make the copying asynchronous

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me! I up-voted this one. I had trouble in Visual Studio 2017 community edition finding the Mcrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel but if you add the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library under COM in the reference manager it will add the assembly to your project.

Comment: Hi, your code worked like a charm, however, i would like to paste some texte in excel before the datagridview; like a title, is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 11):

I did not intend to steal @Jake and @Cornelius's answer, so i tried editing it. but it was rejected. 
Anyways, the only improvement I have to point out is about avoiding extra blank column in excel after paste. Adding one line `dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;` hides so called "Row Header" which appears on the left most part of DataGridView, and so it is not selected and copied to clipboard when you do `dataGridView1.SelectAll();`

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        //to remove the first blank column from datagridview
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
    }
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. It removes the blank rows after every row of my DataGridView.

Answer (score 9):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        int StartCol = 1;
        int StartRow = 1;
        int j = 0, i = 0;

        //Write Headers
        for (j = 0; j < dgvSource.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
            myRange.Value2 = dgvSource.Columns[j].HeaderText;
        }

        StartRow++;

        //Write datagridview content
        for (i = 0; i < dgvSource.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < dgvSource.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
                    myRange.Value2 = dgvSource[j, i].Value == null ? "" : dgvSource[j, i].Value;
                }
                catch
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code, but I would add it's crucial to add these 2 lines: workbook.SaveAs(ExcelFileSavePath); to save it and excel.Quit() to kill the process otherwise it's going to have that read-only message when opening Excel file

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) library. Refer to: [Adding DataTable as Worksheet](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet)

```
var wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook();
DataTable dt = GetTheDataTable();//Refer documentation


wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"FileName.xlsx\"");

using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
    wb.SaveAs(ms);
    ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    ms.Close();
}

Response.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

Interop is slow and has other issues, using the the clipboard seems non extensible. 
Here are two other ways to do this

1. Work with Excel 2007+ files directly instead of working with Excel, it'll be much (much) faster. You can use OpenXML (http://openxmldeveloper.org/) which is Microsoft's SDK. The best way to learn OpenXML is to download the Productivity tool ([http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124), ittakes an existing file and generates the code required to create it. Another, perhaps simpler, option is to use ClosedXML (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/). It seems a lot easier to use (look at the example http://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Showcase&referringTitle=Home), but I have no experience with it. I'm sure there are other libraries that wrap work with Excel.
2. Work with excel via OLEDB. This allows you to work with Excel as if it's a dababase. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB or [Performance of OLEDB to read Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312661/performance-of-oledb-to-read-excel) for examples and more details.

I'd start with ClosedXML.

Comment: You're not wrong but this is a link only answer. It doesn't actually contain a solution but a suggestion. This would make a better comment.

Answer (score 3):

I like Jake's solution. The problem with no header is resolved by doing the following

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Header 1";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Header 2";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Header 3";
```

of course this only works is you know what the headers should be ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

that's what i use for my gridview,  try to use it for yr data , it works perfectly  :

```
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText+";");

        }


        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text+";");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the first question, why it takes so much time and it offers an alternative solution for exporting the DataGridView to Excel.

MS Office Interop is slow and even Microsoft does not recommend Interop usage on server side and cannot be use to export large Excel files. For more details see [why not to use OLE Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) from Microsoft point of view.

Interop saves Excel files in XLS file format (old Excel 97-2003 file format) and the support for Office 2003 has ended. Microsoft Excel released XLSX file format with Office 2007 and recommends the usage of OpenXML SDK instead of Interop. But XLSX files are not really so fast and doesn’t handle very well large Excel files because they are based on XML file format. This is why Microsoft also released XLSB file format with Office 2007, file format that is recommended for large Excel files. It is a binary format. So the best and fastest solution is to save XLSB files.

You can use this [C# Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) to save XLSB files, but it also supports XLS and XLSX file formats.

See the following code sample as alternative of exporting DataGridView to Excel:

```
// Create a DataSet and add the DataTable of DataGridView 
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add((DataTable)dataGridView);
//or ((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Copy() to create a copy

// Export Excel file 
ExcelDocument workbook = new ExcelDocument();
workbook.easy_WriteXLSBFile_FromDataSet(filePath, dataSet, 
     new EasyXLS.ExcelAutoFormat(EasyXLS.Constants.Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), 
     "Sheet1");
```

If you also need to export the formatting of the DataGridView check this code sample on how to [export datagridview to Excel in C#](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-datagridview-to-excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

This line works only for the DataGridView Control on Windows Forms:

```
DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
```

This one addresses the same issue, but for the DataGrid control for the WPF Framework:

```
    private void copyDataGridContentToClipboard()
    {
        datagridGrupeProductie.SelectAll();
        datagridGrupeProductie.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;

        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, datagridGrupeProductie);
        datagridGrupeProductie.UnselectAll();
    }


    private void rightClickGrupeProductie_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        copyDataGridContentToClipboard();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWkbk;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWksht;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelWkbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        excelWksht = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWkbk.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWksht.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        excelWksht.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGridView's `RightToLeft` set to `Yes` then your data copy reversely. So you should use the below code to copy the data correctly.

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
{
    dgvItems.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
    dgvItems.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dgvItems.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    dgvItems.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**alternatively** you can perform a fast export without using Office dll, as Excel can parse csv files without problems.

Doing something like this (for less than 65.536 rows with titles):

```
  Try

            If (p_oGrid.RowCount = 0) Then
                MsgBox("No data", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "App")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

            Dim sText As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            Dim sTmp As String
            Dim aVisibleData As New List(Of String)

            For iAuxRow As Integer = 0 To p_oGrid.Columns.Count - 1
                If p_oGrid.Columns(iAuxRow).Visible Then
                    aVisibleData.Add(p_oGrid.Columns(iAuxRow).Name)
                    sText.Append(p_oGrid.Columns(iAuxRow).HeaderText.ToUpper)
                    sText.Append(";")
                End If
            Next
            sText.AppendLine()

            For iAuxRow As Integer = 0 To p_oGrid.RowCount - 1
                Dim oRow As DataGridViewRow = p_oGrid.Rows(iAuxRow)
                For Each sCol As String In aVisibleData
                    Dim sVal As String
                    sVal = oRow.Cells(sCol).Value.ToString()
                    sText.Append(sVal.Replace(";", ",").Replace(vbCrLf, " ; "))
                    sText.Append(";")
                Next
                sText.AppendLine()
            Next

            sTmp = IO.Path.GetTempFileName & ".csv"
            IO.File.WriteAllText(sTmp, sText.ToString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            sText = Nothing

            Process.Start(sTmp)

        Catch ex As Exception
            process_error(ex)
        Finally
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
        End Try
```

Comment: (for less than 65.536 rows with titles) - What does this mean? @Caveman

Comment: @PratikBhavsar I mean that Excel only admits 65.536 rows for a sheet

Comment: Thanks, anyway I figured exporting to CSV is handier since no additional DLLs are required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer because none of the other methods use OpenXMLWriter, despite the fact that it is faster than OpenXML DOM and both faster and more reliable than COM/Interop, and because some of the other methods use the clipboard, which I would caution against, as it's output is unreliable.

The details can be found in my answer in the link below, however that example is for a DataTable, but you can adapt it to using a DataGridView by just changing the row/column loops to reference a dgv instead of a dt.

[How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel/61644625#61644625)