# Export dataGridView data to Excel on button click throwing system level exception on user's computer

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am using the copy and paste method to export the results from a data grid view to excel. Copy method is working fine, but the opening a new spreadsheet and pasting the data is throwing a exception once I deployed the program to another user. The feature works just fine on my computer so I am wondering if there is an excel add-in that is required or a setting I am overlooking?

My code is as follows:

try
{

```
            copyAlltoClipboard();
            Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.Visible = true;
            xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
            CR.Select();
            xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, true);
          


        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error triying to PasteSpecial a datagridview-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914513/exception-from-hresult-0x800a03ec-error-triying-to-pastespecial-a-datagridview)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, I am looking for a free commercial use solution to the problem. EPPlus carries a licensing cost.

Comment: The Excel library requires Excel to be installed on the client's computer.  Does the target computer have a version of excel?  What was the error btw?  Because of this I lean towards exporting csv format where possible.  It's a pretty universal format.

Comment: Yes the user does have excel/ office 365 just as I do. the error I am getting is as follows:System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID ..... failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).