# I want export datagrid to excel in wpf C# and code is error at GetClipboardContent()?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a bundle code which work well in Winform to WPF.
Code is error at `GetClipboardContent()`;
I use:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.IO;

public class MyCommon
{
    private static MainWindow mainWindow;

    public static void copyAlltoClipboard()
    {
        mainWindow.grdKQ_TASK.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = mainWindow.grdKQ_TASK.GetClipboardContent(); 
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

    public static void releaseObject(object obj) 
    {
        //same at other post
    }

    public static void export2excel() 
    {
        copyAlltoClipboard();
        //same at other post
    }
}
```

Error:

> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'GetClipboardContent' and
>   no extension method 'GetClipboardContent' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

the function export datagrid to excel which I got at here, at 2 second answer: [How to export dataGridView data Instantly to Excel on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182029/how-to-export-datagridview-data-instantly-to-excel-on-button-click)
 How to solve it?

Comment: Can you kindly add the error to the question?

Comment: 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'GetClipboardContent' and no extension method 'GetClipboardContent' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I am assuming you're getting a compile time error, and the reason for it is pretty straightforward : the datagrid has no method named `GetClipboardContent` (because it is a WPF control, and does not have the same implementation as the winforms datagrid). the proper course of action would be to find a different way to get the data to the clipboard, or properly serialize and/or export it from your model (rather than a control)

Comment: Might i ask why you intend to use the clipboard rather than writing the data you are using straight to the sheet via excel interop?

Comment: Please teach me how to using straight to the sheet via excel interop. a sample code is good refer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView.GetClipboardContent() equivalent on DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478342/datagridview-getclipboardcontent-equivalent-on-datagrid)

Comment: `GetClipboardContent()` is a method of winforms `DataGridView`. It won't work on wpf `DataGrid`. Surprise, surprise

Comment: At conclusion, can you teach me another way to export datagrid to excel in WPF, mr ASh?

Answer (score 0):

I final found another way to solve my problem above, replace clipboard by a datatable to store datagrid view.

```
  using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
  private void btnEX_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Excel.Application excel = null;
        Excel.Workbook wb = null;

        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
        Excel.Range rng = null;

        try
        {
            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Add();
            ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

            DataView view = (DataView)grdKQ_TASK.ItemsSource;
            DataTable dt = DataViewAsDataTable(view);

            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Columns.Count; Idx++)
            {
                ws.Range["A1"].Offset[0, Idx].Value = dt.Columns[Idx].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int Idx = 0; Idx < dt.Rows.Count; Idx++)
            {  

                ws.Range["A2"].Offset[Idx].Resize[1, dt.Columns.Count].Value = dt.Rows[Idx].ItemArray;
            }


            excel.Visible = true;
            wb.Activate();
        }
        catch (COMException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Excel: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public static DataTable DataViewAsDataTable(DataView dv)
    {
        DataTable dt = dv.Table.Clone();
        foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
            dt.ImportRow(drv.Row);
        return dt;
    }
```

I hope to help someone.