# How can I pass the values that I have in a DataGridView to an Excel and show it in the corresponding cells?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Windows Form in which I have a dataGridView and I want that when I press a button that I have programmed, I open the Excel application and pass the values that I have in the cells of the dataGridView to the corresponding cells in Excel.

I have the following code but it only introduces me the first value and the doubt that I have is that how do I do so that I enter as many values as I have filled cells in the dataGridView?

```
Excel.Application objExcel = new Excel.Application();
objExcel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook objLibro = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
Excel.Worksheet objHoja = (Excel.Worksheet)objLibro.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range objRango;
objRango = objHoja.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
```

I have tried the following code but I miss error in the application by the CR.Select () command;

```
private void copyAlltoClipboard()
{
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    DataObject dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    copyAlltoClipboard();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
    xlexcel.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
    CR.Select();
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
}
```

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182029/how-to-export-datagridview-data-instantly-to-excel-on-button-click

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work for me, it gives me an error and it does not pass the values to Excel.

Comment: The given link has many, many suggestions. Did you try all of them? Please work through everything, find the approach that comes closest to working for you, then use the [edit] link below the question to modify it. Insert the link as a reference. Then copy in the code you tested. Point out which line is causing an error, and what the error is. This will give people a way to reproduce your exact problem.

Comment: I have already edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ideas fro you to try.  Import from Excel to DataGridView; export from DGV to Excel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", "C:\\Users\\Ryan\\Desktop\\Coding\\DOT.NET\\Samples C#\\Export DataGridView to Excel File & Export to Text File\\Import_List.xls");
            using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection)) //rename sheet if required!
                    dbAdapter.Fill(table);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                int rows = table.Rows.Count;

                this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            }
        }

         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                // creating Excel Application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook =  app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;                   

                // see the excel sheet behind the program
                app.Visible = true;


               // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
               // store its reference to worksheet
               worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
               worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

               // changing the name of active sheet
               worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";


               // storing header part in Excel
               for(int i=1;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1;i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i-1].HeaderText;
                }


                // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
                for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }


                // save the application
                workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                // Exit from the application

              app.Quit();
            }

         private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

            SqlConnection cnn ;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;
            connectionString = "data source=Excel-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Products";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }



        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0; 

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount  - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("c:\\test.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\test.xls");
        }

        //Note this part of code gets data from DataGridView and fills cells.
        // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
        //for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
        //{
        //    for(int j=0;j<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
        //    {
        //        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        //    }
        //}

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This line of code creates a text file for the data export.
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Excel_Files\\Book1.txt");
            try
            {
                string sLine = "";

                //This for loop loops through each row in the table
                for (int r = 0; r <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
                {
                    //This for loop loops through each column, and the row number
                    //is passed from the for loop above.
                    for (int c = 0; c <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; c++)
                    {
                        sLine = sLine + dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                        if (c != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                        {
                            //A comma is added as a text delimiter in order
                            //to separate each field in the text file.
                            //You can choose another character as a delimiter.
                            sLine = sLine + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    //The exported text is written to the text file, one line at a time.
                    file.WriteLine(sLine);
                    sLine = "";
                }

                file.Close();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Export Complete.", "Program Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (System.Exception err)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                file.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int WORKSHEETSTARTROW = 1;
            const int WORKSHEETSTARTCOL = 1;

            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            Excel.Workbook excelbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)excelbk.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
            int worksheetRow = WORKSHEETSTARTROW;
            for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; rowCount++)
            {
                int worksheetcol = WORKSHEETSTARTCOL;
            for (int colCount = 0; colCount < dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; colCount++)
            {
                Excel.Range xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Cells[WORKSHEETSTARTROW, worksheetcol];
                xlRange.Value2 = dataGridView1.Columns[colCount].Name;
                worksheetcol += 1;


                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[rowCount].Cells[colCount].Style.Font != null)
                    {
                        xlRange.Font.Bold = dataGridView1.Rows[rowCount].Cells[colCount].Style.Font.Bold;
                        xlRange.Font.Italic = dataGridView1.Rows[rowCount].Cells[colCount].Style.Font.Italic;
                        xlRange.Font.Underline = dataGridView1.Rows[rowCount].Cells[colCount].Style.Font.Underline;
                        xlRange.Font.FontStyle = dataGridView1.Rows[rowCount].Cells[colCount].Style.Font.FontFamily;
                    }
                    worksheetcol += 1;
                }
                worksheetRow += 1;

            }
        }
    }
}
```